# Potential buffer overflow when using realpath() in C

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, realpath

I am reading this [link](https://pentestmag.com/write-secure-code-cc-programming-languages/) related to secure coding in C. It contains the following paragraph:

> In C and C++ programming languages, some functions take string as
> input. Examples include realpath(), syslog() and getopt(). When such
> functions are injected with an extensive amount of input buffer, a
> buffer overflow attack can take place. As such, a good coder will
> establish the greatest possible length of such input string required
> for a particular program and shorten input strings appropriately prior
> to invoking the realpath(), syslog() and getopt() functions.

Taking `realpath()` as example, the function [signature](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) is:

```
char *realpath(const char *path, char *resolved_path);
```

Based on the function signature, when someone calls this, they would have allocated and filled in the memory for the `path` argument. If the memory size allocated for the `resolved_path` result is not large enough, it may cause overflow. Is this analysis correct ? I'm not sure why the link I gave above says buffer overflow due to extensive amount of input buffer.

Comment: "*extensive amount of input buffer*" sounds like a roundabout (and borderline confusing) way to say "*return string bigger than the buffer allocated to receive it*". This is also what the BUGS note in the `realpath` man page alludes to: "*The POSIX.1-2001 standard version of this function is broken by design, since it is impossible to determine a suitable size for the output buffer, resolved_path*".

Comment: You're right and the link is wrong, or at least not well worded.  The length string returned by `realpath` isn't directly dependent of the length of the input string; it also depends on what symlinks exist in the filesystem and so forth.  If the output buffer is large enough (`PATH_MAX` on Linux), there is no need to do anything to the input.

Comment: you have `_POSIX_PATH_MAX ` that could help allocate a sufficiently large buffer